# Get the Last Access Time for a File

Tags: java, file, lastaccesstime

I know that using `File` object we can get the last modified time for a `File` (i.e. [File.lastModified()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified--)). But, my requirement is to get the *last accessed time* for a `File` in Java. How do I get it?

Comment: Bear in mind that this information isn't reliable. People (myself included) typically turn off atime as it greatly speeds up disk access. People do it on servers too.

Comment: I'll second cletus. I turned atime on my WinXP off when I bought a SSD drive. That SSD wasn't good with random writes, and updating the last access times was killing my machine on otherwise read-only operations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You will need to use [the new file I/O API (NIO2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) which comes with Java 7. It has a method [lastAccessTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html#lastAccessTime()) for reading the last access time.

Here is a usage example:

```
Path file = ...
BasicFileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);
FileTime time = attrs.lastAccessTime();
```

For more information see [Managing Metadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html) in the Java Tutorial.

Comment: i would like to know how java 7 gets the last accessed time.

Comment: Java 7 asks for it from the operating system, using some OS specific function. Is that what you wanted to ask? I've added an example of how Java 7 can be *used* to get the time, in case you meant instead that.

Comment: BasicFileAttributes cannot be resolved. I am using Java 1.8. What could be wrong?

Comment: Does that mean the file has to be last opened in order for **lastAccessTime** to return correct value?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it with plain Java, you'll need to use JNI to access the platform specific data such as this or use [extensions to the core Java library](http://www.javaxt.com/) like the following:

```
javaxt.io.File file = new javaxt.io.File("path");
file.getLastAccessTime();
```

Or, if you have Java 7, go with Esko's answer and use NIO.