# How to get date and time of last access of any file in java programmatically?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the last access time for a file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920259/getting-the-last-access-time-for-a-file-in-java)

I'm using JDK 1.6 and tried various times for getting the Date and time of last access of 
a file.

But could not find exact solution.

Comment: This link shows you how to get *last access* of a file and not just last modified: [Getting the last access time for a file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920259/getting-the-last-access-time-for-a-file-in-java)

Comment: The last access time isn't very reliable. If I do a word search or backup a directory, it could result in every file being accessed. Some filesystems don't even support access date/times

Comment: Last access what? Last read, modify, create or what?

Comment: last access means last time opened,read?

Comment: sir,Plz give me the soultion so that i can get the last access,creation date of a file in java6 only and its very urgent for me?

Answer (score 1):

[File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) has `lastModified()` method, which you can use.

Comment: OP asks for last access time, not last modification time

Answer (score 0):

`java.io.File#lastModified()` returns the date when the file is last modified as a long, i.e number of milliseconds since jan 1 1970. You can set that in a `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar` to get human readable date.

Comment: OP asks for last access time, not last modification time!

Comment: Ah! thanks @MykeMierz, I didn't read it carefully enough :(

Answer (score 0):

In 1.6 as people have said you can get the last modified date. Not hte last accessed date though.

If you can access to java 7 then there is the [BasicFileAttibutes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/BasicFileAttributes.html) interface that would give you this information. For example

```
Path file = ...
BasicFileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);
attrs.lastAccessTime();
```

Comment: but it is the requirement  of head that i have do it only in java 6

Comment: then I think you can only get the lastModifiedTime unless you use JNI and talk to the OS directly. Last accessed is not too reliable. Searching a directory can give false results on this

Comment: what is JNI and how can we use JNI. Can u please elaborate?

Comment: JNI = [Java Native Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) - a way to call native code from Java (and vice versa).

Comment: Last Access Time
Knowing when a file or directory was last accessed is a key attribute for monitoring and auditing file systems. This important attribute is available on both Windows and Unix/Linux file systems. The javaxt.io.File and javaxt.io.Directory classes both provide methods to retrieve the last access time. Here's an example of how to retrieve the last access time for a file:

javaxt.io.File file = new javaxt.io.File("/temp/file.txt");
System.out.println("Accessed: " + file.getLastAccessTime());

Comment: javaxt is an extension to the core library. My solution uses java 7 core libraries